# Why am I getting "function not found" Bash Shell Scripting

Tags: bash, function, shell

I've created a script that deletes users off a linux system. I created a few functions, but when I run the script, it says "function not found" for all of my functions. I verified that when I call them, they are spelled correctly.  Here's one of my functions.

```
function process_answer
{
case $ANSWER in
y|Y|YES|yes|Yes|YeS|yEs|yES|yeS|yES|YEs )
;;
*)
echo
echo $EXIT_Line1
echo
echo
exit
;;
esac
unset $EXIT_Line1
unset $EXIT_Line2
} #end of process answer
```

Comment: Please include the code sample as a code block in the question rather than a link to a screenshot.

Comment: Can you also provide an example of what you tried to execute and the exact error message?

Comment: @busybear Done. sorry. I'm new to stack overflow

Comment: How are you calling your function? Within the same script?

Comment: Yes. I call them multiple times throughout the same script @busybear

Comment: `$: declare -l ans; ans=YeS; case "$ans" in; y|yes) echo "$ans";; esac`

Comment: Note that you unset the variable **name** not the variable **value**: do `unset var` not `unset $var`

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE**

It seemed that I put my shabang line on the second line of the script. I placed it back onto the first line, and everything worked fine.